# What is the difference between ForSqlServerHasIndex and HasIndex when configuring models in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When I configure models in Entity Framework, I can do both

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
    .HasIndex()
```

and

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
    .ForSqlServerHasIndex()
```

What is the difference between using the two?

If there some performance benefits that comes from using the second version, and creating a closer coupling to SQL Server, or is it some sort of internal method called by Entity Framework, when creating indexes for SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForSqlServerHasIndex` is misleading and has nothing to do with SQL Server. The only difference between it and the corresponding `HasIndex` method is the return type - generic `IndexBuilder<TEntity>` vs non generic `IndexBuilder`. The former simply allows lambda overload of the custom `ForSqlServerInclude` and other *standard* fluent APIs while with the later currently you can only use overloads with string property names.

The return type of the typed `HasIndex` is simply wrong. It's a bug / leftover from EF Core fluent API evolution over the time. And will be fixed in 3.0 - see [Breaking Changes - ForSqlServerHasIndex replaced with HasIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#forsqlserverhasindex-replaced-with-hasindex)
.

Shortly, there is no *functional* difference between the two. So in case you don't need typed lambda expression extensions of `IndexBuilder<TEntity>`, use `HasIndex` instead. And if you do use `ForSqlServerHasIndex`, be prepared to change it when upgrading to 3.0+.